# Specific Draw region within Game Window

Tags: c#, xna, scroll, draw, popupwindow

Part of the problem I am having with what I am trying to do is trying to explain to others what I want. What I am trying to accomplish is an in-game pop-up menu or window which has its own Draw area. For example lets say I have a pop up window with multiple objects stacked on top of each other, such as button, but there are too many to fit on the window so you need a scroll bar to move them into view. What I want to do is make these object only Draw inside of the window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6zJi.jpg

The black area with scribbled pink is the main game window and the centre image is the pop up windows, the dark blue squares being the objects inside. Any code, suggestions, and mainly theory will be appreciated. I've tried drawing them only when they're inside the window and this works but it doesn't look very smooth, I want the object gradually disappearing as they move out the window, not just vanishing when they touch the borders, and especially not slipping out of the window.

Thanks.

Comment: What platform are you using to write this game? How to show a pop-up window varies depending on the platform. You should be more specific about the environment, and you should make some effort to solve this yourself so that you can then explain what already _didn't_ work and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do any rendering in XNA you can set the ViewPort on the GraphicsDevice.  This lets you restrict where things are being rendered.

For example, if you want to render something to a 100x100 pixel area at the top-left of your screen you might do:

```
            // Create the rectangle
            var clipRectangle = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(0,0,100,100);

            // Set the rectangle when you call SpriteBatch.Begin:
            mSpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, renderStates.BlendState,
                samplerState,
                depthStencilState,
                rasterizerState,
                null, matrix, 
                clipRectangle);
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with the .Begin constructor only taking a maximun of 8 constructors? however your answer gave me a better idea of how I need to go about solving my problem and after some much more educating googling I think I came across my answer: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/viewports-split-screen

Comment: I tried using two different viewports in my Draw() method but the only one that appears to function is the one that is used last, everything else drawn in the previously used viewports doesn't appear seem to appear.